# How session '$config['sess_expiration']' expires in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to know how session expires in CodeIgniter, because before `$config['sess_expiration']` expires ie destroys, I want to insert the logout time of the particular user.I want to know where the flow goes so that I can write a query to insert user logout data.In which file session destroy code is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```
if($login_var) {
   $this->session->sess_expire_on_close = TRUE;
} else {
   $this->session->sess_expire_on_close = FALSE;
}
```

Comment: ,i have to take user id before  session destroys automatically will it be Possible.to insert the logout time of particular user.

Comment: You have to apply condition when the user logout and save that time.

Comment: will it be possible to get the the time when session expire automatically. The 'time' when the user make no activity and session destroys.

Comment: This [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/520237/how-do-i-expire-a-php-session-after-30-minutes) answer will help you a lot.

Comment: Thank for great help